# Network-Font with glyph variations is displayed wrong in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, truetype

I have a very strange phanomen. First, I used this HTML code to display a font for testing:

```
<html style="margin:0; padding:0; height:525px; width:525px;">
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <body style="margin:0; padding:0; height:525px; width:525px;">
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 10px">10: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 11px">11: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 12px">12: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 13px">13: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 14px">14: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 15px">15: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 16px">16: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 17px">17: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 18px">18: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 19px">19: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 20px">20: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 21px">21: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 22px">22: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 23px">23: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 24px">24: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 25px">25: test llll 123</span>
     
   </body>
</html>
```

The font "Zfull-BIG5" is installed on my computer (Windows 11). The output looks fine: [image]

Then i tried to use network ressources:

```
<html style="margin:0; padding:0; height:525px; width:525px;">
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <header>
      <style>* { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }</style>
      <style>@font-face {
    font-family: "Zfull-BIG5";
    src: url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/cfdb2532f2c9299da3c61fa9c953583d.eot");
    src: url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/cfdb2532f2c9299da3c61fa9c953583d.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/cfdb2532f2c9299da3c61fa9c953583d.woff2")format("woff2"),
    url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/cfdb2532f2c9299da3c61fa9c953583d.woff")format("woff"),
    url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/cfdb2532f2c9299da3c61fa9c953583d.ttf")format("truetype"),
    url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/cfdb2532f2c9299da3c61fa9c953583d.svg#Zfull-BIG5")format("svg");
}</style>
   </header>
   <body style="margin:0; padding:0; height:525px; width:525px;">
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 10px">10: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 11px">11: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 12px">12: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 13px">13: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 14px">14: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 15px">15: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 16px">16: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 17px">17: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 18px">18: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 19px">19: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 20px">20: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 21px">21: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 22px">22: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 23px">23: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 24px">24: test llll 123</span><br>
     <span style="font-family: Zfull-BIG5; font-size: 25px">25: test llll 123</span>
     
   </body>
</html>
```

The output is now completly different:

[image]

I also tried only using the ttf in the font-face, with the same not working result.
It seems that the browser can not display the font directly if it is loaded from the web.
You can find the font-face generated code here: https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/cfdb2532f2c9299da3c61fa9c953583d

Comment: Seems like you local version is other hinting instructions (especially size 10-19px) – so it's not identical with the web version. Are both renderings from a browser screenshot? Maybe the cdn version was reduced (stripping some hinting data) to provide a smaller filesize.

Comment: I downloaded the font also from the same link and installed it locally, so it is definitely the same font. Both screenshots are from the browser.
I also see in the network tab of chrome that the same file size is downloaded.

Comment: It also seems that this is working:
``src: local('Zfull-BIG5') url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/cfdb2532f2c9299da3c61fa9c953583d.ttf")format("truetype")``
I chcked the local installed file with the donwloaded file from the URL with win merge, they are the same.

Comment: this is indeed weird. If both fonts are identical the rendering should be as well. I could reproduce this behavior in Firefox on win 10. It seams like browsers omit certain hinting instructions that are available when rendering a local font. As different browsers produce slightly different renderings my spectulation is that FF applies something like a "passthrough" mode leaving the text rendering to window's native text rendering subsystem. I'm afraid there's not much you can do about it.